# Stop dropdown from expanding div above

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

Fellow Coders,

I encountered a problem while putting dropdown menu into my app's navigation. When I drag my mouse over my dropdown element, menu below expands together expanding div element above (which is dropdown menu's name) and pushing all other items in navigation's menu to the right side. Here is my code:

```
const listItems = links.map((link_name) =>
  <li className="nav-item" key={link_name}>
    <div className="nav-link"><DropDown name={link_name} /></div>
  </li>
);
return (
  <nav className="navbar-light" style={{ backgroundColor: '#333333' }}>
    <div>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
          <img alt="dribbble" style={styles.style_img} src={"http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/dribbble_logo_detail.png"} />
        </Link>
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav" style={styles.style_l}>
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    </div>
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav" style={styles.style_r}>
        {this.renderLinks()}
        <li className="nav-item" key={10}>
          <input type="search" ref="city" placeholder="Search"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
);
const styles = {
 style_r: {
  margin: 10,
  top: 5,
  right: 17,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 'auto',
  position: 'fixed',
 },
 style_l: {
  margin: 5,
  top: 10,
  left: 134,
  bottom: 20,
  position: 'absolute',
 },
 style_img: {
  margin: 5,
  left: 10,
  width: 100,
  height: 42,
 }
 };
```

dropdown is defined as:

```
if(this.state.menuActive) {
  menu = <div>
            <ul className="drop">
              <li>First Item </li>
              <li>Second Item </li>
              <li>Third Item </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
} else {
  menu = "";
}
return (
  <div id = "menu">
    <div id = "dropdown_name" style={{ color: '#F5F5F5' }} onMouseOver = { this.toggleMenu } onMouseLeave = { this.toggleMenu }>{this.props.name}</div>
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName = "menu" transitionEnterTimeout={1000} transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
      {menu}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
)
```

if I put style={{ position: absolute }} on div (dropdown_name), in my nav bar every element collides into one gibberish weird looking unreadable name...

and here's mine css:

```
    .menu-enter {
      max-height: 0px;
      -webkit-transition: max-height;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .menu-enter.menu-enter-active {
      height: auto;
      max-height: 100px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .menu-leave {
      max-height: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: max-height;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .menu-leave.menu-leave-active {
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    ul.drop {
      margin-top: 7px;
      background-color: #333333;
      color: #6D6D6D;
      border: #333333 solid 7px;
      -moz-border-radius: 7px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
      width: 100%;
      padding-left:0.4em;
      font-size: 12pt;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
```

How can I prevent dropdown from expanding my dropdown's name above? I want that my divs that represent dropdown's names would remain the same width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning):

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static).

Keep your absolute positioning on the dropdown component, and place a `position: relative;` style on the dropdown's container component (`nav-link`). This will allow the dropdown to be positioned relative to it's containing nav link.

It seems like your issue with every element combining when you added the absolute position was because they were all being absolutely positioned to the body element.

Comment: It did nothing. Then I placed `position: absolute` on `<div id="menu">` from dropdown component, and, finally, when I drag my mouse over dropdown's divs, they don't expand like I wanted BUT all those divs are still all placed in one same position creating same clashed name...
Tried to place `position: relative` to all higher elements but seems like it has zero impact.

Comment: When you say "nothing", you mean the UI looked exactly the same as before? It sounds like you don't have a solid understanding of CSS positioning. Maybe you can start at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position and read more about it.

Comment: You issue seems to be only about CSS, and is unrelated to reactjs. Can you reproduce your problem on codepen or jsfiddle (or any other similar service)? This will really help in trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding `style={{ position: 'absolute', whiteSpace: 'nowrap', width: 'auto' }}` to my menu's div. Thank you for your responses!